# Calculate perfect width of TextBlock with text containing unicode characters

Tags: wpf, textblock

I have the following text in a TextBlock:

> textBlock1.Text="Welcome! The \u25Bc Unicode Consortium enables people \u25Bc around the world to use computers \u25Bc in any language. Our freely-available specifications \u25Bc and data form \u25Bc the foundation for software \u25Bc internationalization in all \u25Bc major operating systems, search engines, applications, and the World Wide Web."

properties of TextBlock :

```
textBlock1.FontSize=22;
textBlock1.FontFamily="Segoe UI";
```

Here `\u25Bc` is my special unicode character.
How can I calculate the perfect width of the TextBlock without any variations?
The width needs to be perfect as I am using it to provide animation to `textBlock1`.

Comment: have you tries this code: double i= textBlock1.ActualWidth;

Comment: Yes but it does not give perfect width

Answer (score 1):

`ActualWidth` works for me:

```
<Window x:Class="widthtest.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">

<StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Left">

    <TextBox x:Name="text" 
             FontFamily="Segoe UI" 
             FontSize="22" 
             Text="Welcome! &#x25BC; The &#x25BC; Unicode Consortium" />

    <Border Margin="0,10" 
            Background="Blue" 
            Height="{Binding ActualHeight, ElementName=text}" 
            Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=text}" />

</StackPanel>
</Window>
```

[image]